# how to add dictionary data in to an array?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have made an array and a dictionary. now i want to put the values of dictionary in to array.. i am very new to objective C so kindly help.
"viewcontroller .m"

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

marray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4", nil];
marray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];
[self displayarray];
[marray release];
mDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[mDictionary setValue:@"sdfsdhfg" forKey:@"firstname"];
[mDictionary setValue:@"kvxv" forKey:@"lastname"];
[self displaydict];
[mDictionary release];
}
-(void)displaydict{
CFShow(mDictionary);
}
-(void)displayarray{
for (int i = 0; i<[marray count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"the array data present at %d index is %@",i,[marray objectAtIndex:i]);
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question contains so many other questions, I will try to solve few of them related to converting dictionary to array.

1. Store all keys

   ```
   NSArray *dictKeys=[dict allKeys];
   ```
2. Store all values

   ```
   NSArray *dictValues=[dict allValues];
   ```
3. If you want to store both keys and values:

   ```
   NSArray *keysAndValues=[dictKeys arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dictValues];
   ```

---

EDIT:

As you require NSMutableArray, you can use :

```
NSMutableArray *dictAllKeys=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict allKeys]];
NSMutableArray *dictAllValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict allValues]];
NSMutableArray *keysAndValues=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictAllKeys arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:dictAllValues]];
```

Comment: but if i am taking NSMutableArray instead of NSArray its not working.. can u elaborate a little bit. thank you.

Comment: No a big issue... whatever method NSArray contains are inherited by NSMutableArray.... in few cases you need to adjust a bit... I am updating my answer in few secs

Answer (score 3):

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in arrayname)
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"writeKey"];
}
```

This might help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the values of Dictionary, use particular key for values. For that use the following format.

```
NSArray *yourarray=[YourDictionary ObjectForKey:@"KEY"];
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: `O` of objectForKey should be small, and there will be only one object  for a given key, it must be an array to store in yourArray.

Comment: the "ObjectForKey" will return any Object that may be array or one object, that's not a problem. If you want another solution, why don't you gor for "ObjectAtIndex" in Dictionary.